# fluxcd failure after first access

Tags: git, github, kubernetes, devops, fluxcd

I have a funny situation with my fluxcd workload on k8s. I am trying to configure fluxcd workload on my k8s (on eks) to deploy app from my repo. The log shows that it was able to access github and found new released k8s object files. but all subsequent access return this error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

K8s version = 1.18
flux version = 1.21.0

Any suggestion on diagnosing this issue?
Here is the full log.

```
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.660683058Z caller=main.go:259 version=1.21.0
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.660729123Z caller=main.go:412 msg="using kube config: \"/root/.kube/config\" to connect to the cluster"
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.694067171Z caller=main.go:492 component=cluster identity=/etc/fluxd/ssh/identity
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.694102094Z caller=main.go:493 component=cluster identity.pub="ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx fluxcd"
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.694126615Z caller=main.go:498 host=https://172.20.0.1:443 version=kubernetes-v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.694166271Z caller=main.go:510 kubectl=/usr/local/bin/kubectl
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.695265432Z caller=main.go:527 ping=true
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.695536819Z caller=main.go:666 url=ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git user=xxx email=xxx@xxx.com signing-key= verify-signatures-mode=none sync-tag=build-flux-sync state=git readonly=false registry-disable-scanning=true notes-ref=build-flux-sync set-author=false git-secret=false sops=false
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.695576145Z caller=main.go:751 component=upstream URL=ws://fluxcloud
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.696562798Z caller=upstream.go:133 component=upstream connecting=true
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.696893569Z caller=main.go:795 addr=:3030
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.696977557Z caller=loop.go:67 component=sync-loop info="Registry scanning is disabled; no image updates will be attempted"
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.697063581Z caller=sync.go:51 component=daemon warning="failed to load last-synced resources. sync event may be inaccurate" err="git repo not ready: git repo has not been cloned yet"
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.697104186Z caller=loop.go:108 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git repo has not been cloned yet"
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:41.699018988Z caller=upstream.go:147 component=upstream connected=true
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:42.174047585Z caller=checkpoint.go:24 component=checkpoint msg="up to date" latest=1.20.1
ts=2021-01-22T07:11:52.629446199Z caller=loop.go:134 component=sync-loop event=refreshed url=ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git branch=xxx HEAD=ad71e60d5b61fb17c85646c5ef3af010f33ca2ec
ts=2021-01-22T07:13:29.206177525Z caller=sync.go:61 component=daemon info="trying to sync git changes to the cluster" old=3d3df47da9826002698e9d6faef603347d71607d new=ad71e60d5b61fb17c85646c5ef3af010f33ca2ec
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:38.430957604Z caller=sync.go:79 method=Sync info="not applying resource; ignore annotation in file" resource=flux:deployment/flux source=fluxcd/deployment-flux.yaml
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:38.431682477Z caller=sync.go:540 method=Sync cmd=apply args= count=67
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:40.412253941Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=1.980475048s err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found\nError from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output="namespace/admin unchanged\nnamespace/backstage unchanged\nnamespace/cert-manager unchanged\nnamespace/default unchanged\nnamespace/flux unchanged\nnamespace/kube-node-lease unchanged\nnamespace/kube-public unchanged\nnamespace/kube-system unchanged\nnamespace/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged\nserviceaccount/efs-provisioner unchanged\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/efs-provisioner-runner unchanged\nserviceaccount/fluent-bit created\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fluent-bit-read created\nserviceaccount/flux configured\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flux configured\nservice/fluxcloud configured\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created\nrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/leader-locking-efs-provisioner unchanged\nservice/memcached configured\nserviceaccount/metrics-server unchanged\nservice/metrics-server unchanged\nservice/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged\nserviceaccount/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged\nrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-key-admin unchanged\nrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-service-proxier unchanged\ncustomresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/sealedsecrets.bitnami.com unchanged\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/secrets-unsealer unchanged\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader unchanged\nclusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged\nconfigmap/fluent-bit-config created\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fluent-bit-read created\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flux configured\npersistentvolumeclaim/flux-tmp configured\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx created\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created\nrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/leader-locking-efs-provisioner unchanged\nrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader unchanged\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator unchanged\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/run-efs-provisioner unchanged\nrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged\nrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-service-proxier unchanged\nclusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged\ndeployment.apps/efs-provisioner configured\ndaemonset.apps/fluent-bit created\ndeployment.apps/fluxcloud configured\ndeployment.apps/memcached configured\ndeployment.apps/metrics-server unchanged\ndeployment.apps/sealed-secrets-controller configured\nstorageclass.storage.k8s.io/aws-efs-standard unchanged\nstorageclass.storage.k8s.io/ebs-csi-gp2 unchanged\nsealedsecret.bitnami.com/git-ssh-key configured\nvalidatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission created\napiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:40.811174903Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=398.82547ms err=null output="namespace/admin unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:41.394748916Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=583.515075ms err=null output="namespace/backstage unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:41.900681885Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=505.881649ms err=null output="namespace/cert-manager unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:42.397868741Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=497.106578ms err=null output="namespace/default unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:42.891058742Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=493.137805ms err=null output="namespace/flux unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:43.413384242Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=522.267484ms err=null output="namespace/kube-node-lease unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:43.913865089Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=500.425913ms err=null output="namespace/kube-public unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:44.408359028Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=494.417052ms err=null output="namespace/kube-system unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:44.99409166Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=585.68475ms err=null output="namespace/kubernetes-dashboard unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:45.487302521Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=493.154343ms err=null output="serviceaccount/efs-provisioner unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:45.986967413Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=499.613885ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/efs-provisioner-runner unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:46.507919018Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=520.893135ms err=null output="serviceaccount/fluent-bit unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:47.023825463Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=515.859875ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fluent-bit-read unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:47.4935634Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=469.689953ms err=null output="serviceaccount/flux unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:47.912133528Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=418.525693ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flux unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:48.387499012Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=475.318357ms err=null output="service/fluxcloud unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:48.871262811Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=483.705164ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:49.397015116Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=525.697104ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:49.87199228Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=474.919539ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:50.355258006Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=483.211989ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:50.812340209Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=457.025093ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:51.355618608Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=543.227442ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:51.872033727Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=516.367722ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:52.371578968Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=499.49742ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:52.798805188Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=427.180173ms err=null output="role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/leader-locking-efs-provisioner unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:53.292518268Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=493.664061ms err=null output="service/memcached unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:53.695930907Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=403.364685ms err=null output="serviceaccount/metrics-server unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:54.193472131Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=497.485626ms err=null output="service/metrics-server unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:54.70293546Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=509.415046ms err=null output="service/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:55.205694885Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=502.704135ms err=null output="serviceaccount/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:55.694254797Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=488.509092ms err=null output="role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-key-admin unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:56.208222605Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=513.920697ms err=null output="role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-service-proxier unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:56.694122349Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=485.841913ms err=null output="customresourcedefinition.apiextensions.k8s.io/sealedsecrets.bitnami.com unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:57.211083636Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=516.911932ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/secrets-unsealer unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:57.692955699Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=481.822011ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:aggregated-metrics-reader unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:58.105620938Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=412.616954ms err=null output="clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:58.597035893Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=491.365636ms err=null output="configmap/fluent-bit-config unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:59.096279092Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=499.193705ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/fluent-bit-read unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:14:59.609137559Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=512.808678ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/flux unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:00.113543907Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=504.353462ms err=null output="persistentvolumeclaim/flux-tmp unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:00.606935711Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=493.330415ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:01.174866675Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=567.880665ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:01.607053543Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=432.139535ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:02.159227347Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=552.117123ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:02.671269693Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=511.980415ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:03.110989126Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=439.656913ms err=null output="rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/leader-locking-efs-provisioner unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:03.597787026Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=486.74369ms err=null output="rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server-auth-reader unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:04.102917786Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=505.084409ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/metrics-server:system:auth-delegator unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:04.597446493Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=494.473142ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/run-efs-provisioner unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:05.105545977Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=508.051542ms err=null output="rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:05.693874047Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=588.276311ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-controller unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:06.198681789Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=504.759864ms err=null output="rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/sealed-secrets-service-proxier unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:06.707216771Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=508.485939ms err=null output="clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/system:metrics-server unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:07.20203917Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=494.775224ms err=null output="deployment.apps/efs-provisioner configured"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:07.687488657Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=485.401142ms err=null output="daemonset.apps/fluent-bit configured"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:08.197431353Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=509.895359ms err=null output="deployment.apps/fluxcloud unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:08.686987288Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=489.509786ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:09.258416008Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=571.385297ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:09.7778928Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=519.425596ms err="running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found" output=
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:10.2221443Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=444.199377ms err=null output="deployment.apps/memcached configured"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:10.695917417Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=473.723335ms err=null output="deployment.apps/metrics-server unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:11.224662658Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=528.694215ms err=null output="deployment.apps/sealed-secrets-controller configured"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:11.787295286Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=562.582572ms err=null output="storageclass.storage.k8s.io/aws-efs-standard unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:12.206831282Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=419.488021ms err=null output="storageclass.storage.k8s.io/ebs-csi-gp2 unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:12.696859048Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=489.978989ms err=null output="sealedsecret.bitnami.com/git-ssh-key unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:13.216985598Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=520.054356ms err=null output="validatingwebhookconfiguration.admissionregistration.k8s.io/ingress-nginx-admission configured"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:13.69546204Z caller=sync.go:606 method=Sync cmd="kubectl apply -f -" took=478.426535ms err=null output="apiservice.apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io unchanged"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:14.294910311Z caller=sync.go:231 component=daemon err="ingress-nginx:serviceaccount/ingress-nginx: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:role/ingress-nginx: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:role/ingress-nginx-admission: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:service/ingress-nginx-controller: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:rolebinding/ingress-nginx: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:rolebinding/ingress-nginx-admission: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:configmap/ingress-nginx-controller: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:job/ingress-nginx-admission-create: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:job/ingress-nginx-admission-patch: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found; ingress-nginx:deployment/ingress-nginx-controller: running kubectl: exit status 1, stderr: Error from server (NotFound): error when creating \"STDIN\": namespaces \"ingress-nginx\" not found"
ts=2021-01-22T07:15:14.316975589Z caller=daemon.go:704 component=daemon event="Sync: ad71e60, <cluster>:clusterrole/fluent-bit-read, <cluster>:clusterrole/ingress-nginx, <cluster>:clusterrole/ingress-nginx-admission, <cluster>:clusterrolebinding/fluent-bit-read, <cluster>:clusterrolebinding/ingress-nginx, <cluster>:clusterrolebinding/ingress-nginx-admission, <cluster>:validatingwebhookconfiguration/ingress-nginx-admission, admin:configmap/fluent-bit-config, admin:daemonset/fluent-bit, admin:serviceaccount/fluent-bit, ingress-nginx:configmap/ingress-nginx-controller, ingress-nginx:deployment/ingress-nginx-controller, ingress-nginx:job/ingress-nginx-admission-create, ingress-nginx:job/ingress-nginx-admission-patch, ingress-nginx:role/ingress-nginx, ingress-nginx:role/ingress-nginx-admission, ingress-nginx:rolebinding/ingress-nginx, ingress-nginx:rolebinding/ingress-nginx-admission, ingress-nginx:service/ingress-nginx-controller, ingress-nginx:service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission, ingress-nginx:serviceaccount/ingress-nginx, ingress-nginx:serviceaccount/ingress-nginx-admission" logupstream=true
ts=2021-01-22T07:17:02.44292057Z caller=loop.go:108 component=sync-loop err="pushing tag to origin: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n ERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-22T07:17:02.443021657Z caller=loop.go:127 component=sync-loop url=ssh://git@github.com/xxx/xxx.git err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone159237772'...\nERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-22T07:32:02.443091782Z caller=sync.go:51 component=daemon warning="failed to load last-synced resources. sync event may be inaccurate" err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone422736558'...\nERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
ts=2021-01-22T07:32:02.443152229Z caller=loop.go:108 component=sync-loop err="git repo not ready: git clone --mirror: fatal: Could not read from remote repository., full output:\n Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/flux-gitclone422736558'...\nERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n"
```

Comment: Can you show the exact `flux bootstrap` you used please? Also, is the linked log the result of that command, or is the logs of a pod?

Answer (score 2):

For FluxCD to be able to to access the private Github repositories, it needs to be able to authenticate to Github.
You could create a dedicated Flux user, or use your own.

This is done using a Kubernetes secret as such: https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/source/gitrepositories/#ssh-authentication

You can see the various Git authentication methdods supported here: https://fluxcd.io/docs/cmd/flux_create_secret_git/#examples